# Protractor - How can I bypass the mixed content error

Tags: automated-testing, javascript, protractor, cucumber

I am getting the below error when I was trying to approve a document in a webpage

```
Mixed Content: The page at \'https://example.com\' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure resource \'http://insecure-page.com:9870/xyz\'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.'
```

It is because my test is trying to load a non secure page over a secured page. The page is loaded, but I am not able to proceed further. I am using Protractor-cucumber-javascript framework.

Could someone help me to bypass this error so I can continue with the rest of the steps in my automation testing script.

Answer (score 1):

This is actually a *security feature of your browser*.

If you know that the content from this HTTP url is safe, and if you are using Chrome, you should be able to instruct Chrome to load insecure content by specifying [`--allow-running-insecure-content` command-line option](https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/#allow-running-insecure-content) in your config:

```
capabilities: {
  'browserName': 'chrome',
  'chromeOptions': {
    'args': ['--allow-running-insecure-content']
  }
},
```

<sup>*In general, though, this is not ideal security-wise as *all HTTP content* would be allowed for loading.</sup>

Reference materials:

- [Adding Chrome-Specific Options](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/browser-setup.md#adding-chrome-specific-options)
- [Protractor functional test cannot load unsafe http javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40899948/protractor-functional-test-cannot-load-unsafe-http-javascript)

Comment: I am able to load the page ,but not able to proceed with the following automated steps

Comment: @RRR okay, could you be more specific about "not able to proceed with the following automated steps"? Are you getting any errors? Do you have this chrome command-line argument set?

Comment: This argument is set in browser config file.Am getting the above error in browser log that I mentioned in the question and not able to click on a button that needed to be done after loading the document